# Mplayer Fedora No video

Tags: fedora, mplayer

I have installed MPlayer. I have vaio with ATI graphics card. When I try to play movie file such as .avi, MPlayer GUI opens, but there is no video (just white GUI) I can see all the control buttons, it also plays the audio, but no video.

What is the error?

Comment: A question better-suited for http://www.superuser.com/

Comment: I am sorry. how to move it to superuser

Comment: If 5 3000+ rep users vote for it to be moved, it will get moved automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your SMPlayer(MPlayer GUI) setting!
Choose "Option""general"Video""Output Driver""X11"

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, I just install Mplayer that:

```
# ./configure 
# make
# make install
```

It will be install in `/usr/local`

Run properly on my computer